# WIX two msi package provide value

Tags: parameters, wix, bundle, readfile

I'm new in wix.
I have two MsiPackage, and the first MSI get some data from the user, and the secound msi need these values(like parameters). How do I solve?
I tired the first msi write the value to file, and in the bundle read this file value. It is possible?
(Only the first msi is mine , so i can't modify the secound msi)

Comment: Please edit your title to be a sentence or sentence fragment. Tags are sufficient to give the larger context so the don't need to be thrown into the title.

Comment: Would setting any of the public properties of the second MSI help? That's usually how information is intended to be passed into an installer. Take a look at the Properties table with a viewer like [InstEdit](http://www.instedit.com/).